# IPTables - Blocking ports on eth0:x Network Interfaces

Tags: firewall, iptables, interface

I'm wondering, is it possible to block certain ports on different interfaces such as `eth0:0` `eth0:1`...

For instance, if I want to block on `eth0:0` ports `22` and `25` and leave those open on `eth0:1` I'm open to any suggestions!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

This is acheived by using the `-i` option when adding rules to the `INPUT` chain.

Here's an example for what you requested (assuming you default drop on your `INPUT` chain):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -i eth0:1 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -i eth0:1 --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I thought `eth0:0` will be treated just like `eth0:1`...if both are `eth0`. I'm wondering, does iptables support aliases? Note that `eth0` `eth0:0` and `eth0:1` have different IPs assigned.

Comment: From a brief google, it looks like subinterfaces aren't supported by iptables.  I'm awfully surprised by this and I wonder if it's been updated.  I don't have a test system handy to give it a shot.  At any rate, you could use -d <interface ip> instead to filter by "destination IP address".